# For $(x_1,x_2)$, is $G_1(x)=|x_1|$ a norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: normed-spaces

For $(x_1,x_2)$, is $G_1(x)=|x_1|$ a norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

To prove that a function $p$ is a norm we need to prove the following:

- $p(av) = |a|p(v)$
- $p(u + v) \leq p(u) + p(v)$
- $p(v)\ge0$, and if $p(v)=0$ then $v$ is the zero vector

However, I don't know how to actually show this.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Start with an easy example. What is the norm of $(0,1)$?...

Comment: In the last of your three requirements, you probably mean that $v$ should be the zero vector; not $p(v)$.

Comment: Thanks, it's been changed :)

Comment: I think the norm of $(0,1)$ is $1$?

Comment: Think again :) $G_1(0,1)=|0|=0$...

Comment: @Levi: Why do you "think" $G_1((0,1))=1$? The definition of $G_1$ is right in front of you. Use it!

Comment: I thought that in order to calculate the norm of $(0,1)$ we do $\sqrt{0^2+1^2}=1$. But in my lecture notes it does say the norm of $(0,1) = 0$, I'm just not sure how to calculate it.

Comment: The norm $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the usual Euclidean norm, which satisfies all the requirements. In your problem a different norm is defined as : norm of $(x,y)$ is $|x|$. This one doesn't satisfy all three requirements. In checking it you cannot go back to using the Euclidean norm, but must use the one which is defined in the problem.